# rosdep and ROS2?

Tags: ros2, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone tell me the status of rosdep with regards to ROS2? I'm a little confused by the [ROS2 from-source guide](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Linux-Development-Setup/) since it actually does use rosdep, but only after installing a ton of dependencies by hand. Contrast that with the [same guide for ROS1](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source), which only installs enough to get rosinstall files and merge them into a workspace before using rosdep to get all the dependencies.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310728/rosdep-and-ros2?/) by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2018-12-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The instructions explicitly install dependencies not covered by rosdep keys in ROS packages, e.g. `build-essential`, `cmake`, and some tools. That is pretty similar to the ROS 1 instructions in the first section "Installing bootstrap dependencies".

In ROS 2 we additionally need to install a few `pip` packages just because the available Debian packages are too old.

Anything beyond that is coming in via `rosdep` - as in ROS 1.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3